# iOS Navigation Controller will not move to the next View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I've already solved the problem. I'm just posting my results since it may help others.

I have a `UITabBarController` with a `UINavigationController` and a `UIViewController` being pushed onto the `UINavigationController`. I used to have only 2 tabs on my `UITabBarController`, but now I have 6. So I have a "More" button that has to be pushed in order to see the additional tabs. Whenever I try to push a `UIViewController` in any of my tabs under "More" my app doesn't switch to the `UIViewController`. The viewDidAppear function doesn't get called or anything.

Here's my code:

```
if (newViewController == 0)
    newViewController = [[NewViewViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"NewViewControllerXIB" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];

TestAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TestAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.navController pushViewController: newViewController animated: true];
```

Comment: Accept your own answer.

Comment: I will when it allows me to in two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, if you're using a `UITabBarController` and your controller has so many tabs it will have a "More" button created, and your controller will be placed into a premade `UIMoreNavigationController`. So rather than getting the navigation controller that your shared application delegate is using, you need to use the `UIMoreNavigationController` that was created for you. So you want to do this instead:

```
if (newViewController == 0)
    newViewController = [[NewViewViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"NewViewControllerXIB" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController: newViewController animated: YES];
```

I'm going to start pushing all my view controllers to the navigation controller it is apart of from now on. Lesson learned.